# A Verb for a Child Conducting a Conversation between Toys

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I feel like there is a word (more specific than conducting) for this, and that I might even have known it at one point. The word, of course, doesn't have to be limited to this one situation with a child and toys, but it seemed to be the easiest way to get across the idea.

> She ___ the dolls talking about their day.

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: 'Orchestrate' perhaps comes close, but 'She orchestrated the dolls talking about their day' doesn't work. 'She orchestrated the imaginary conversation.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's just about the same as "conducting," coming close to fitting the meaning. If a better word doesn't come up I may actually use orchestrate, since it would fit my situation rather well. I'm embarrassed I hadn't thought of that, really.

Comment: According to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/orchestrate),  'If you say that someone orchestrates an event or situation, you mean that they carefully organize it in a way that will produce the result that they want.' 'Conduct' isn't normally used in this way except in musical performances; 'conduct an inquiry' merely means 'carry out an inquiry'.

Comment: She had the dolls "talking" about their day.

Comment: My son used to call it "talking his little people".

Comment: 5 answers: no joy!  appears theer is no such specific verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Voiced* can convey the idea of speaking for another.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that a good word for your sentence is ***enacted***.

Definitions of *enact:*

> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/enact):
>
>   to perform a story or event as a play
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=enact):
>
>   To act (something) out, as on a stage:  enacted the role of Romeo.

… or perhaps ***playact***:

> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/playact):
>
>   - Act in a play.
>
>     Act (a scene, role, etc.).
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/playact):
>
>   - to take part in theatrical performances
>       especially as a professional
>
>     to make believe

Note: *enact* is listed by twice as many dictionaries as list *playact*.

Other words I looked at and dismissed include “dramatize”, “portray”, “simulate” and “depict”. 
If you don’t like the two words I chose,
maybe you’ll prefer one of these alternatives;
or you can look them up in a thesaurus and get even more synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

[**Direct**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/directed)

> transitive
>
> **3 a** : to regulate the activities or course of · *directs* a staff of over 200 employees
>
> **b** : to carry out the organizing, energizing, and supervising of · *direct* a project · *directed* a call center
>
> **c** : to train and lead performances of · *direct* a movie · *directing* a famous actor
>
> **d** : to dominate and determine the course of
>
> intransitive
>
> **2** : to point out, prescribe, or determine a course or procedure

The word seems more natural and specific to me than *orchestrated* or even *manipulated*.

She assigns roles involving actions and dialogue to the toys and has them play their parts (along with props, costumes, and sets)—just as an actual director would do with actors.

> She directed the dolls conversation about their day.

Answer (score 0):

“She was doing some pretend play in which her dolls were talking about their day”.

‘Pretend play’: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/moral-landscapes/201404/is-pretend-play-good-kids

Answer (score -1):

She `had` the dolls talking about their day.

This word feels best to me. Assuming that the reader understands that the dolls possess no motive force of their own, it implies that she is directing them, conducting them and orchestrating the conversation.

Comment: +1 for a simple word that solves the problem perfectly.